# C# | Поиск по тексту

Tags: c#, .net, текст, полнотекстовый-поиск

В тексте необходимо найти все имена, подпадающие под определенную категорию.
Сложность в том, что текст может иметь разную структуру.
Есть какой-то умный текстовый поиск или какой-то алгоритм  для поиска по тексту, может кто сталкивался подскажет???

Пример текста:

> Таким образом, повышение уровня гражданского сознания обеспечивает актуальность позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач? Не следует, однако, забывать о том, что **Михайлов Александр Дмитриевич** и
> **Мешков Дмитрий Тимофеевич** а так же **Афанасьева Малика Андреевна** совместно с **Максимов Михаил Алиевич** повышают уровень гражданского сознания напрямую зависит от ключевых компонентов планируемого обновления?

К примеру в таком тексте найти ФИО..

Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Я вижу такой алгоритм, который хоть и не самый надежный, но вам подойдет: 1) разделить текст на предложения и предложения на слова 2) пройтись последовательно по словам каждого предложения и найти последовательности из трех слов, у которых первая буква заглавная. Это и будет ваши ФИО. Единственный минус - любое перечисление слов, которые начинаются с заглавных букв, тоже будут подпадать под этот алгоритм. Другой вариант - использовать базу Имен и Отчеств, и искать их соответствия в тексте. Более надежный, но более сложный вариант

Comment: Ну если ФИО всегда из трёх слов с большой буквы, то попробовать искать такие сочетания регулярным выражением.

Answer (score 0):

Ой, только я тут на `Python` исходник даю, привык всё на нём делать. Но в `C#` регулярка будет точно такая же.

Вот вам простейший вариант по идее, которую я писал ранее в комментарии. Как-то вроде можно ещё сократить эту регулярку, но я не очень умею:

```
import re

text = 'Таким образом, повышение уровня гражданского сознания обеспечивает актуальность позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач? Не следует, однако, забывать о том, что Михайлов Александр Дмитриевич и Мешков Дмитрий Тимофеевич а так же Афанасьева Малика Андреевна совместно с Максимов Михаил Алиевич повышают уровень гражданского сознания напрямую зависит от ключевых компонентов планируемого обновления?'
r = re.compile('([А-Я][а-я]+\s+[А-Я][а-я]+\s+[А-Я][а-я]+)')
print(r.findall(text))
```

Вывод:

```
['Михайлов Александр Дмитриевич',
 'Мешков Дмитрий Тимофеевич',
 'Афанасьева Малика Андреевна',
 'Максимов Михаил Алиевич']
```